# Toggling one div on and the other off using .toggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how can I toggle two divs using.toggle I have the following so far:

```
$('#toggler').change(function() {
    $('#div1').toggle();
    $('#div2').toggle();
});
```

toggler is a checkbutton - I want div 1 to appear when true and div 2 to disappear and the opposite to happen when false, any ideas?

EDIT** - I can't use .hide() as if I start the page with the checkbutton selected the toggle will be around the wrong way

Comment: What you have will do exactly that, as long as one starts out hidden, and the other visible.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a boolean value in the toggle()

```
var isChecked = $('#toggler').is(':checked');

$('#toggler').change(function() {
    $('#div1').toggle(isChecked);
    $('#div2').toggle(!isChecked);
});
```

jQuery documentation -

```
$( "#foo" ).toggle( showOrHide );
```

is equivalent to -

```
if ( showOrHide === true ) {
    $( "#foo" ).show();
} else if ( showOrHide === false ) {
    $( "#foo" ).hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/sWJ9u/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#toggler').change(function () {
        var input = $(this);
        var div = input.is(':checked') ? $('#div1') : $('#div2');
        $('div').hide();
        div.show();
       });
});
```